# PHP curl_error doesn't return an error when using CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl in PHP to make a post request to a database. The request looks something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, getenv('DATABASE_URL'));
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data, '', '&'));  
      $output = curl_exec($ch)
```

where $data is defined earlier. The request uses a token as verification, and if the token is invalid, the above $output is the error message

```
{"error":"You do not have permissions to use the API"}
```

which is good. So I want to catch that error to handle it properly further down the program, so I use curl_error($ch) to do so. The problem is, this returns the empty string which according to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) corresponds to no errors. I have also tried the curl_errno to count the numbers, but this returns 0 errors.

Can anyone see my mistake(s)?

Comment: It looks like that you are getting response from the server, even its error message as json. If so then no error occurred during curl request and request completed successfully.

Comment: this seems to be a valid response. which means there is no curl error. if you want to throw an error just json_decode the `$output` and throw it yourself when error is set and not empty.

Comment: Also [curl_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) expects curl resource as parameter i.e. `$ch` not the result variable like `curl_error($output)`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I of course run curl_error($ch), typo.

Comment: Ah of course. So the curl request is valid, but the server reject the request, I see. Thank you so much for the answer.